# Creating roles with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have tried almost all of the code snippets online and when I tried them I always get an error that says `ReferenceError: guild is not defined.`

```js
case 'setup':
if (msg.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "role")) return msg.reply('bot is already setup')
guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'role',
    color: 'GREY',
  },
  reason: 'idfk',
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, you need to define `guild` or in this case, say which `guild` you're creating the `role` in, which would be `msg.guild`, the `guild` the message was sent in.

```js
case 'setup':
if (msg.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "role")) return msg.reply('bot is already setup')
msg.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'role',
    color: 'GREY',
  },
  reason: 'idfk',
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
break;
```